# How i can declare a vector in RISC V assembly?

Tags: vector, riscv

in mips, i can do(Work's fine):

1. .data
2. a:  .word -7,8,107,11,13    #vector

but in the simulator Ripes, i can't do it, it's a error or have other mode to write the "vector"?

Comment: which simulator are you using , and how does it  hang-up ? normally if your code assembles well, it should be working on the simulator.

Comment: Ripes, https://github.com/mortbopet/Ripes
the simulator don't recognize the code.

Comment: https://github.com/TheThirdOne/rars recognizes this and may be a good option for you to use if you are still trying to learn risc-v assembly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.word`-declaration is [defined](https://github.com/riscv/riscv-asm-manual/blob/master/riscv-asm.md) as `.word   expression [, expression]*  32-bit comma separated words` and your code compiles with `gcc`, so I think the simulator 
just doesnt support it.